# How to set the background of a material design button wihout a shadow appearing?

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design

Using material designs when the background of a button is set, a shadow appears. How would I disable the shadow and possibly remove the rounded corners?

Example:

```cs
...
 <Button Grid.Column="1" Background="{StaticResource BurgundyLightBrush}" Command="{Binding Path=EditSwitchCommand}"  >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Edit" />
            </Button>
...
```

[Resulting appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSr63.png)

[Ideal appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdoKu.png)

Changing the border thickness and zindex hasn't fixed this and so far the only solution would be to add a rectangle behind the button with the chosen brush. So far my solution has been to make the button transparent and place a rectangle behind, however this seems "hacky" and makes my xaml harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the styles which are included in the Material Design In XAML project.
I'd suggest one of the following (for your use-case):

- MaterialDesignFlatButton
- MaterialDesignIconButton
- MaterialDesignFlatLightButton
- MaterialDesignFlatMidButton

You should clone the [Material Design in XAML repository](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/) and checkout the demo app to see live visuals.

This answer assumes the latest version of Material Design in XAML (which is 3.0.0 at the time of writing).

Style source: [Github](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Button.xaml)